# How do I create a RedPanda Cluster using 3 VMs WITHOUT docker and kubernetes?

Tags: cluster-computing, redpanda

I am following https://docs.redpanda.com/docs/deploy/deployment-option/self-hosted/manual/production/production-deployment/#default-deployment to create the cluster.

I created three droplets in DigitalOcean and followed the above document.But RedPanda cluster is not created.

`rpk cluster info` shows

```
CLUSTER
=======
redpanda.2039f084-c8f9-40ef-9665-bec4464d4b75
BROKERS
=======
ID    HOST     PORT
0*    0.0.0.0  9092
```

redpanda.yaml files of the hosts are as follows:

HOST 1

```
node_uuid: 1456d234-e657-11ed-92d9-8631248eafd2
redpanda:
    data_directory: /var/lib/redpanda/data
    seed_servers: []
    rpc_server:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port: 33145
    kafka_api:
        - address: 0.0.0.0
          port: 9092
    admin:
        - address: 0.0.0.0
          port: 9644
rpk:
    enable_usage_stats: true
    tune_network: true
    tune_disk_scheduler: true
    tune_disk_nomerges: true
    tune_disk_write_cache: true
    tune_disk_irq: true
    tune_cpu: true
    tune_aio_events: true
    tune_clocksource: true
    tune_swappiness: true
    coredump_dir: /var/lib/redpanda/coredump
    tune_ballast_file: true
pandaproxy: {}
schema_registry: {}
```

HOST 2

```
node_uuid: 29ef514c-e657-11ed-8e7a-c24bc2a25245
redpanda:
    data_directory: /var/lib/redpanda/data
    empty_seed_starts_cluster: false
    seed_servers:
        - host:
            address: 10.104.0.2
            port: 33145
        - host:
            address: 10.104.0.3
            port: 33145
        - host:
            address: 10.104.0.4
            port: 33145
    rpc_server:
        address: 10.104.0.3
        port: 33145
    kafka_api:
        - address: 10.104.0.3
          port: 9092
    admin:
        - address: 10.104.0.3
          port: 9644
rpk:
    enable_usage_stats: true
    tune_network: true
    tune_disk_scheduler: true
    tune_disk_nomerges: true
    tune_disk_write_cache: true
    tune_disk_irq: true
    tune_cpu: true
    tune_aio_events: true
    tune_clocksource: true
    tune_swappiness: true
    coredump_dir: /var/lib/redpanda/coredump
    tune_ballast_file: true
pandaproxy: {}
schema_registry: {}
```

HOST 3

```
node_uuid: 2bef5fb2-e657-11ed-9db0-16328b7bffdf
redpanda:
    data_directory: /var/lib/redpanda/data
    empty_seed_starts_cluster: false
    seed_servers:
        - host:
            address: 10.104.0.2
            port: 33145
        - host:
            address: 10.104.0.3
            port: 33145
        - host:
            address: 10.104.0.4
            port: 33145
    rpc_server:
        address: 10.104.0.4
        port: 33145
    kafka_api:
        - address: 10.104.0.4
          port: 9092
    admin:
        - address: 10.104.0.4
          port: 9644
rpk:
    enable_usage_stats: true
    tune_network: true
    tune_disk_scheduler: true
    tune_disk_nomerges: true
    tune_disk_write_cache: true
    tune_disk_irq: true
    tune_cpu: true
    tune_aio_events: true
    tune_clocksource: true
    tune_swappiness: true
    coredump_dir: /var/lib/redpanda/coredump
    tune_ballast_file: true
pandaproxy: {}
schema_registry: {}
```

Please help and thanks in advance